# If $a$ and $b$ are algebraic, then $\frac ab$ is algebraic

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-numbers

> Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are algebraic over field $\mathbb F$ and $b \neq 0$, then $\frac ab$ is algebraic over $\mathbb F$.

I know that algebraic means that there are polynomials $f$, $g$ such that $f(a)=0$ and $g(b)=0$, but I don't know how to continue, I have never solved problems like this..

I have seen a similar question:
[Prove: if $a$ and $b$ are algebraic, then $a + b$, $a - b$ and ab are also algebraic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237425/prove-if-a-and-b-are-algebraic-then-a-b-a-b-and-ab-are-also-algeb)
but I did not understand the answer using field extensions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$? Where's your work?

Comment: Can you prove that  $ab$ and $1/b$ are algebraic?

Comment: For $a$ and $b$ I found this question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237425/prove-if-a-and-b-are-algebraic-then-a-b-a-b-and-ab-are-also-algeb?fbclid=IwAR3qSNG7SxGsJD7flW5lGh70p-GmpXCDMbK-bHXF0z2Oya4dfFhGwp9ylag

but I did not really understand the answers.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes and votes to close if you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: The answer to the linked question, using field extensions, is the natural way to attack this question. If that material is unfamiliar to you then you should [edit] the question to tell us what you do know about fields and algebraic numbers and the tools you can use. If you have been asked to prove this for a course you have probably been given some such tools.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ might both be algebraic integers, $\frac{a}{b}$ might not be. But it will certainly be an algebraic number, e.g., $\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 3}$.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for an approach without field extensions:

As you already mentioned, there are monic polynomials $f,\;g$ such that $f(a)=0$ and $g(b)=0.$ 
Wolog $g(0)\neq 0$. If it was, the whole polynomial could be divided by the variable and would still fulfill $g(b)=0.$

Let $A$ be the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)  of $f$ and $B$ the companion matrix of $g.$ $B$ is invertible because $g(0)\neq 0.$ One of the eigenvalues of $A$ is $a,$ and one of the eigenvalues of $B$ is $b,$ which means that one of the eigenvalues of $B^{-1}$ is $b^{-1}.$

Now set $C=A\otimes B^{-1}$ ([Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)). Then one of the eigenvalues of $C$ is $ab^{-1},$ which means that $ab^{-1}$ is one of the roots of the characteristic polynomial $\chi_C$. This makes $ab^{-1}$ algebraic over $\mathbb{F},$ because all of the elements of $C$ are in $\mathbb{F}.$ Therefore, all coefficients of $\chi_C$ are in $\mathbb{F},$ too.